# this binding vs e.currentTarget vs e.target

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

MDN says: ([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener))

> When attaching a handler function to an element using
>   addEventListener(), the value of `this` inside the handler is a
>   reference to the element. It is the same as the value of the
>   `currentTarget` property of the event argument that is passed to the
>   handler.

But when I tested this (using this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jd50d2sw/) it appears, `e.target` is equal to `this` not `e.currentTarget`.

Am I wrong, or MDN needs update?

Comment: Works ok here. When click in red box, shows "outer", "outer", "outer". When click in blue box, shows "outer", "inner", "outer". What result are you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e.target returns the dom element that triggered the event. So if you click on a paragraph it returns p. e.currentTarget however returns the tag that triggered the event and only that tag.